# Get User ID from Unique DIscord Invite Link or Invite with Extra Parameters

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a web where the users fill some information and can get points doing some tasks/games, and I want to match their discord user when joining my discord server to their profile on my web's database so that I can give some rewards depending on certain things on Discord. I have been trying to find an easy way of tracking who joins the server but I couldn't find anything clear.
I know that I can generate unique links with just 1 use and have my bot check whenever that changes, but this brings some issues (at least in my head) if I have multiple people joining at the same time.

The workaround that I have right now is sending a message with my bot to every person that joins with a unique link that goes to an endpoint on my web and I match the data on both sides that way, but it is not the nicest approach.

```
new Event("guildMemberAdd", (client, member) => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(IDofTheChannel);
    if (!channel) return;
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

    embed
        .//My embedded message functionality with the link and so on;

     channel.send({
        embeds: [embed]
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to track this or retrieve information from the invite itself or send the invite with extra parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

---

No, but yes. No as you can't see which invite did a certain GuildMember joined with.
But there's a workaround by tracking invite data.

### Long answer

---

There's no possible way to know if a certain GuildMember joined with which invite because do not send or track this info.
The only workaround I can think of so far is to **track invite uses**.
Let's get straight to the solution

- You'll need to cache all the invites in the Guild by making either a [Map](https://mdn.io/Map) or a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection) and setting all invite codes as the key and uses as the value.
- Listen for the `guildMemberAdd` event and inside you will need to loop through all invites to see which invite data have changed.
- Store your data somewhere and increment the number of invite uses.
- And on top of that, you have to detect which invite is added or deleted so you can set and unset values.
  This can be achieved by listening to `inviteCreate` and `inviteDelete` event.

### ...and there you have it!

---

You've just created an invite tracker, congratulations.
If you need any more explanations, feel free to use the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That functionality is the 1 use link that I was talking about (I liked the idea of 1 use link more than multiples uses, the server is not public), but I think if I have 2 people joining at the same time, I will end un crossing data and that is dangerous on this case since there are benefits involved. If no one else replies in some days with a better option, I'll accept it as answer :)

Comment: Hello, `guildMemberAdd` can't be emitted at the same time, Javascript is single-thread. And no matter what, API wouldn't send them add the same time anyways. The is the best approach and is what all bots I saw do so far.

Comment: But my db is not, so I could be adding 3 links while the discord bot detected just 1 person because the user is in between (I think(?)). At the same time, the plan is for this to grow a lot, so having to check and match a table with 50k entries comparing values sounds not that nice. But it looks like there are not that many options left. Thanks

Comment: Hmm. What about your caches, could you just use the cached count to write to the database? Because it updates right after someone joins. The DB may rewrite the data a lot of times but it atleast it works. This may not be a good practice. But there's almost no options left.

Comment: I guess that might work... But it sounds riskier than what I am doing right now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same headache and the best solution to this problem that I found out is:

You need to use the discord OAuth2 API service to let the user authorize you to access a temporary token which will enable you to use the Discord API to get the user's `id` and other information into your web application. Then, you can pass the user id to your bot, which can be listening to an async server or a database addition/change trigger to give that role to the user.

Reference: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2